# How to replay packets using a specific source-destination port pair?

Tags: pcap, tcpreplay

I have a pcap file with ISAKMP packets and the source port of the packet is a random port and the destination port is 500. I am trying to replay the packets using tcpreplay, but the packets are getting dropped at the receiving device because the ports do not match. Is there any way I can replay my packets by specifying the source and destination ports?